# Why is my upstart script failing?

Tags: ubuntu, debian-jessie

here is the script in question:

```
description "Circuit server"
author      "anonymous"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown

# Script fails when setuid and setgid are not commented
setuid sentimens
setgid sentimens

script

    echo $$ > /var/run/circuit.pid
    exec /bin/circuit start --docker

end script

pre-start script
    echo "[`date`] Circuit Server Starting" >> /var/log/circuit.log
end script

pre-stop script
    rm /var/run/circuit.pid
    echo "[`date`] Circuit Server Stopping" >> /var/log/circuit.log
end script
```

With the addition of the `setgid` and `setuid` lines, I can no longer start my service:

```
$ sudo service circuit start
start: Job failed to start

$ init-checkconf /etc/init/circuit.conf 
File /etc/init/circuit.conf: syntax ok
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.  What is the likely cause of this error given that `init-checkconf` seems happy?

Comment: Check the obvious: permission problems.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, That is indeed the problem.  The user can't write to `/var/run`, but I'm unsure of the security implications behind granting access to that directory.  I guess that's fodder for another question, though.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Make a subdirectory in /var/run, have it owned by the correct user then write the PID there instead.